# Error con BigDecimal en Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

tengo un error con una variable de tipo BigDecimal en Java.

En la aplicacion basicamente digamos que tu tienes una deuda, y puedes añadir X cantidad y en la pantalla te sale tu deuda, el dinero que has aportado, el dinero restante etc..

La cantidad como ya he dicho es una variable de tipo BigDecimal, y estoy haciendo pruebas y por ejemplo tengo una deuda de > 8.000.000.000 y hasta 6.000.000.000 me deja pagar sin problemas, a partir de ahi me salta un error, si meto por ejemplo 7.000.000.000 me da error, no se si puede ser por algo del BigDecimal o algun problema mio en el codigo pero si es asi llevo un rato buscando y no lo encuentro, ademas me daria error tambien con todo.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás declarando la variable?, muestra el código por favor.

Comment: private BigDecimal importeCobro;

Comment: ¿Eso es todo? ¿Cómo asignas valores a la variable? No creo que tu código sea secreto de estado, por favor muestra en la pregunta cómo estás procediendo para poder ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: Perdona,public void setImporteCobro(BigDecimal importeCobro) {
  this.importeCobro = importeCobro;
 }

Comment: y lo saco con public BigDecimal getImporteCobro() {
  return importeCobro;
 }

Comment: Bueno, ya estoy llegando a pensar que es código ultra secreto. Con eso no podemos ver nada. ¿Cómo instancias la clase, cómo le pasas datos reales? ¿Cómo es el constructor de la clase? Eso es lo que interesa ver.

Comment: Si no subes más código, y a la pregunta original, nadie te va a poder ayudar.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y colocar el código, por favor? Es la única manera de poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Solicita ayuda pidiendo a Dios no encontrarla. (¬_¬)!